# Why does the middle row disappear when I use rowspan in top and middle row?

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table

When I try to display the following information:

```
AB
AF
GF
```

and collapse the cells containing the common data the middle row disappears and I get:

```
AB
GF
```

In all cases the number of cells specified appears to be 6.

"completely":

```
3 <tr>s
2 <td>s per <tr>
```

"rowspan first":

```
3 <tr>
1st <tr> <td rowspan='2'> <td>,
2nd <tr> 1st cell covered by previous <td rowspan='2'> <td>
3rd <tr> 2 <td>s
```

"rowspan first and second":

```
3 <tr>s
1st <tr> <td rowspan='2'> <td>
2nd <tr> 1st cell covered by previous <td rowspan='2'> <td rowspan='2'>
3rd <tr> <td> 2nd cell covered by previous <td rowspan='2'>
```

The HTML & CSS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>test rowspan</title>
  <style>
table.b, table.b td, table.b th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>This passes NU HTML Checker, so the syntax seems to be correct</p>
  <p>completely specified</p>
  <table class='b'>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
      <tr><td>A</td><td>F</td></tr>
      <tr><td>G</td><td>F</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>with rowspan first line only</p>
  <table class='b'>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td rowspan='2'>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
      <tr><td>F</td></tr>
      <tr><td>G</td><td>F</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>with rowspan first &amp; second lines combining F, middle row disappears</p>
  <table class='b'>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td rowspan='2'>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
      <tr><td rowspan='2'>F</td></tr>
      <tr><td>G</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p>with rowspan second line only</p>
  <table class='b'>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td</tr>
      <tr><td>A</td><td rowspan='2'>F</td></tr>
      <tr><td>G</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI you are missing a closing bracket in the last td of the first row of your last table. Not sure if that's an error in transcription or an actual bug in the code on your local side.

Comment: error in transcription, original file passes W3C checker

Comment: "with rowspan first & second lines combining F, middle row disappears" --> it doesn't disappear. It doesn't contain any individual cells, to it only has minimal height. If you look close, A and F overlap a bit (vertically), or better said: F starts before A ends (vertically)

Comment: The reason you have different table output for your tables is that you have different table *data*. Rowspan doesn't intelligently collapse cells with the same data, so I'm not sure what you are *expecting* to see. Rowspan tells the column to take up (or *span* across) `n` number of rows. If you have zero-content rows then it'll show as Johannes said: overlapping a bit.

Comment: OK, if I add single <td>s to each row at the end, the middle row now appears.  But how do I display the 2×3 table with the two 'A' cells and the two 'F'  displayed using rowspan?

Comment: I think it's just a limitation of the HTML Tables implementation, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middle row is collapsing because you've removed all the data items from that row. It comes back as long as you add some data to it, which is probably the ideal solution. However, if the table absolutely must only display 2 columns you can create a 3rd hidden column to make the table render how you'd like:

```css
.table-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

table.b td, table.b th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.hidden-column {
  margin-right: -17px;
}
```

```html
<p>completely specified</p>
<div class='table-container'>
  <table class='b'>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
      <tr><td>A</td><td>F</td></tr>
      <tr><td>G</td><td>F</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<p>rowspan=2 on A column</p>
<div class='table-container'>
  <table class='b'>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td rowspan='2'>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
      <tr><td>F</td></tr>
      <tr><td>G</td><td>F</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<p>rowspan=2 on F column</p>
<div class='table-container'>
  <table class='b'>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr>
      <tr><td>A</td><td rowspan='2'>F</td></tr>
      <tr><td>G</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<p>rowspan=2 on A & F columns (with 3rd dummy column)</p>
<div class='table-container'>
  <table class='b'>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td rowspan='2'>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>
      <tr><td rowspan='2'>F</td><td>C</td></tr>
      <tr><td>G</td><td>C</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<p>rowspan=2 on A & F columns (with 3rd dummy column but hidden)</p>
<div class='table-container'>
  <table class='b hidden-column'>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td rowspan='2'>A</td><td>B</td><td class="hidden">C</td></tr>
      <tr><td rowspan='2'>F</td><td class="hidden">C</td></tr>
      <tr><td>G</td><td class="hidden">C</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

It's a little bit hacky but works fine for one-off tables. If you're going to be putting a bunch of dynamic content into the table, or rendering a dynamic number of rows and columns with different rowspans and colspans, you'd probably be better off implementing this layout with something more robust like CSS Grid.

Comment: @jfwfmt if my answer solved your problem please consider upvoting it as well, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, cool! I understand there there must be "content" in the middle for it to display, but I would have thought that the "rowspan"s that included "A" and "F" would be considered "content" for the middle row.